# Correct syntax for iterating through elements selected via data attribute

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, attributes

So I've got the following, which works fine:

```js
var sidebar1 = document.querySelector("[data-language-key='sidebar-1']").innerHTML;
```

But for scalability purposes, I'd like to create an array `sidebar` and use a `for` loop to store all the `sidebar-X` text values. I have written out something already but I can't get the syntax to work.

```js
var sidebar = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

  sidebar.push(document.querySelector(`[data-language-key=`
    'sidebar-' + i ``).innerHTML);

}
```

Comment: You can code with back ticks. `[data-language-key=sidebar-${I}]` It's just a tip for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the value of `[data-language-key]` because you'll have to edit your code if you add new sidebar elements. Just use that selector but with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to pick them all up. Then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the node list (after coercing it to an actual array), and return each element's text content.

```js
const selector = '[data-language-key]';
const els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

const sidebar =  Array.from(els).map(el => {
  return el.textContent;
});

console.log(sidebar);
```

```html
<aside>
  <div data-language-key="1">one</div>
  <div data-language-key="2">two</div>
  <div data-language-key="3">three</div>
  <div data-language-key="4">four</div>  
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a variable everytime in iteration:

```
var sidebar = [];
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
     var side = document.querySelector('[data-language-key = "sidebar-'+i+'"]').innerHtml();
    sidebar.push(side);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key value in the querySelector should have as a string. This kind of error occurs usually while coding with DOM. Let me show you the result of your code.

```js
sidebar.push(document.querySelector(`[data-language-key=`
    'sidebar-' + i `]`).innerHTML);
```

This will be read like,

```js
//if i = 0
sidebar.push(document.querySelector(`[data-language-key=sidebar-0]`).innerHTML);
```

HTML tags has attribute's value as string so the querySelector should have a string with quotes.

```js
//if i = 0
sidebar.push(document.querySelector(`[data-language-key="sidebar-0"]`).innerHTML);
```

So to let the querySelector works use like,

```js
sidebar.push(document.querySelector(`[data-language-key="`
    'sidebar-' + i `"]`).innerHTML);
```